# how to change Navigation header widgets value dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, navigation-drawer

I have included Navigation Drawer in my activity and I need to change the nav header widgets (Image view,Text View) value dynamically like loading app user name, profile picture and mobile number. So please help me to do this.
Thanks in advance.

[image: Here is the screen shot of my application]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the header via `NavigationView`:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
ImageView drawerImage = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_image);
TextView drawerUsername = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_username);
TextView drawerAccount = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_account);
drawerImage.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.ic_user);
drawerUsername.setText("User");
drawerAccount.setText("user@gmail.com");
```

Comment: That works for me! Thank you so much.@Exaqt

Answer (score 0):

Look into this [NavigationView.getHeaderView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#getHeaderView(int))

you can get header view

```
View headerView=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

TextView nameTv=(TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeaderView);
nameTv.setText("any string")
```